# wcf service call with webhttpbinding not working when calling from web application when using adfs 2.0 passive authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, adfs2.0

Web application uses adfs 2.0 passive authentication.

I have trouble with calling wcf service which is with webHttpbinding. Trying to call WCF using ajax application / json.

But service is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

As adfs works with https, binding should have security mode = "Transport" .

make sure endpoints are exposed and "WebServiceHostFactory" is not defined in your service .svc markup file. 
It was there in my case.

If you have "WebServiceHostFactory" then no endpoint will be exposed in that case just do not define any endpoint for that wcf in your web config. It will still work.